# What could be the reason for no one answering my question?

Tags: discussion

I have asked a question, which I think is specific enough and could benefit others (I can tell because the problem has been asked many times by people on the some tutorial comments).

There are like 18 people viewed it, yet no one answered. Is it because no one knows the solution, or I am missing something? Before that question I asked something related to it. So I am afraid the administrator thinks that I am spamming or something?

Comment: Can you post the link to the specific question?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932075/how-to-add-or-remove-children-object-while-editing-teh-parent-using-javascript-i) seems to fit the description; 19 views and no answers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're talking about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932075/how-to-add-or-remove-children-object-while-editing-teh-parent-using-javascript-i), you're asking people to dig through an awful lot of code, and not only figure out how it works, but also design a solution specifically for that. That will take time, and it's not really broadly applicable to a lot of people, thus the lack of interest. Also, it's only been three hours since you asked that.

Perhaps if you could further narrow down the problem and where you suspect things are going wrong that would make this a lot easier for people to approach than a wall of code.

Comment: Also worth reading: [The Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable) Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: ... which also has the designed intention of making one go through one's code again. Who knows, one might actually find the problem oneself, and fix it. =)

Comment: Alright, I got it. I will try to redesign the question. Thanks sir.